# Kivy make a grid layout inside a label or button

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Is it possible to have a grid like layout inside a Label or a Button in kivy.

I have an app that takes in a CSV file with product information and I would like to populate MainScreen with rows from a CSV file.
Each row should look like this:

[image: Row]
In the end the Label or Button should be pressable to open a pop up window for confirmation screen for quantity of the product and verify.
Is it even possible or am I approaching it from the wrong angle?

I do not have any code yet to populate the MainScreen with rows but this is how it looks so far.
To clarify. At this moment I don't need help with importing CSV files, but with the method to display it, that matches the above criteria(picture)

Code so far is as follows:
ATmain.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
Window.size = (270, 480)


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    input = StringProperty("")


class MainScreen(Screen):
    username = StringProperty('')


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("app.kv")


class ATApp(App):
    presentation = Builder.load_file("app.kv")
    def build(self):
        return presentation


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ATApp().run()
```

app.kv:

```
# File name: main.py
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:kivy 1.10.1

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    LoginScreen:
        id: login
    MainScreen:
        username: login.input



<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: [1,1,1]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    FloatLayout:
        rows:2
        cols:1
        background_color: 1,1,1,1
        Label:
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5 - 0.3/2, "center_y": 0.4}
            text:"Kasutaja"
            color: 0,0,0,1
        TextInput:
            id: input
            size_hint: (0.3, None)
            height: 30
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5 - 0.3/2, "center_y": 0.3}
            multiline: False

        Button:
            id: confirm_login
            text: "Login"
            size_hint: 0.15, 0.07
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.5 - 0.15/2, "center_y": 0.2}
            background_color: 0.9,0.9,0.9,1
            on_press: self.background_color = (1,0,0,1)
            on_release: root.input = input.text; app.root.current = "main"

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
    Label:

        id:name
        text: root.username
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 30
        size_hint_x: 1
        pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top": 1}


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint_y: None
        size_hint_x: 1
        pos_hint_x: None
        pos_hint_y: 1

        Button:
            text: "Item1"
            color: (0,0,0,1)
            height: self.height
            size_hint_y: None
            size_hint_x: 1
            pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top": 0}
```

I would be very greatful if anyone could as much as point me in the right direction!

Comment: Not clear what you want in your Button. Is your example row an example of a desired Button?

Comment: Yes, sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: The `GridLayout` is a `Widget`, and all `Widgets` support the `on_touch_down` event. So you could just use a `GridLayout` and call your confirmation screen from a method that you bind to the `on_touch_down` event.

Comment: That kind of worked! Unfortunately it made added on_touch_down event to the entire window, not just the GridLayout. Any way to make it GridLayout Widget specific?

Comment: You can check if the touch event is within the `Widget` by using `if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):`, where `self` is the `Widget`. Also, return `True` from that method to signal no further dispatch of that event. The touch events are dispatched to all the widgets, so it is up to your code to decide what to do with it.

Comment: This is great, Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The kivy hack way will be to simply use a `GridLayout` or any layout for that matter then give your layout button properties so it is clickable like so :

```
from kivy.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

#then make a clickable grid
class GridButton(GridLayout, ButtonBehaviour):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    #Then do whatever you want to do
```

Another way to do it I guess would be to use the `on_touch_down` callback and check if the touch is within the widget's bounds